# How do you make multiple details tags on a single page act with an accordion effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use multiple [`details`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/interactive-elements.html#the-details-element) tags on a page. However, some may end up containing a lot of content and for that reason I want to limit only one being open at any given time. This naturally means closing one if it's already open.

Is it possible to close a `detail` tag programmatically using JavaScript?

Comment: there are lot of accordion plugins available

Comment: I know that @Arun P Johny but I have a solution in place  already using the details tag which was fine for almost a year.  Its worked well but suddenly there is a requirement for more content inside some of the tags which makes the pages very deep if more than one is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should do what you want ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JxTXT/)). The `details` element has an [`open` attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/interactive-elements.html#the-details-element) that you can simply remove. I am using jQuery, but it should be straightforward to do the same in vanilla JS.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('details').on('click', function() {
        $('details').removeAttr('open');
    });
});
```

You might want to filter out the `details` tag that the click event was triggered on, but it seems to work this way.